# Typescript is ignoring null or undefined as function return possibility

Tags: typescript

I have a function where should return a LoginResponse type or null but Typescript lint is ignoring the null possibility and just displaying LoginResponse as possible value.

```
export const getSession = (): LoginResponse | null => {
  return null
}
```

[image]

I also tried using undefined without success. Any thoughts?

Comment: `"strict": true` in tsconfig.json

Comment: did typescript switch to the nullable return syntax getSession = (): LoginResponse? => {

Comment: @bturner1273 No. That's not valid syntax and if they did introduce it, they wouldn't break everyone by removing the verbose version

Comment: @AluanHaddad even after change to use strict:true nothing changed.

Comment: Odd, what's `LoginResponse`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad my bad, it worked, I had to restart TS server on VSCode. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

TLDR;

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

**command line:** `tsc --strict`

To understand why the behavior outlined in your question is indeed expected we need to consider two facts:

1. When `--strictNullChecks` is disabled (the default), TypeScript considers `null` and `undefined` to be subtypes of all types other types. That is to say, everything is nullable and undefinable. This means that for any type `T`, `T` is equivalent to  `T | null | undefined`.
   Contrariwise, when `--strictNullChecks` it is enabled,  `T` is distinct from  `T | null | undefined` for all types save `any`.
2. Given two types, `Base` and `Sub` where `Sub extends Base`, their union, `Base | Sub`, is equivalent to just `Base`. Hence, since `null` is a subtype of all types, it is a subtype of `LoginResponse` making `LoginResponse | null` equivalent to `LoginResponse`

To have TypeScript treat `null` and `undefined` as distinct types, unrelated to all others you need to enable `--strictNullChecks`, a powerful TypeChecking option.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

Or, on the command line, `tsc --strictNullChecks.`

The `--strictNullChecks` option is part of the *strict* family of powerful typechecking
options and we can therefore use `--strict`, enabling all of them which is highly recommended, not just because it catches more errors and provides more semantics for those errors, but because it improves the quality of type inferences dramatically, making a lot of code that should intuitively work, in fact work.