# `undefined` not included in union type when returned by a type alias

Tags: typescript, types

The following type alias does not work as expected:

```
type AllowUndefined<T> = T | undefined

type T = AllowUndefined<string>
// yields T = string
// expected T = string | undefined
```

The result does not change if `undefined` is excluded from the type parameter `T` by requesting `AllowUndefined<T extends {}> = ...`

Comment: You haven't enabled `strictNullChecks`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript is ignoring null or undefined as function return possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643683/typescript-is-ignoring-null-or-undefined-as-function-return-possibility)

Comment: @VLAZ Many thanks! That was the problem. My project has many folders and for that folder the tsconfig was not setup correctly.